# Getting net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on web application PHP

Tags: php, apache

I've got a problem since about 15 days on a Windows server (working since 4 years) which shows up a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET for the client connecting to the web app. This happens once or twice a day at anytime. The bug last for 10 minutes and everything comes back to normal after that.

On the local machine PhpMyAdmin works and accesses to the Database.

Restarting Apache and Mysql services doesn't help. Restarting the server does.

In the error or access logs nothing is added during the bug, and nothing special before the bug. Nothing special either in Windows events viewer.

The configuration :
Windows server 2012
Apache 2.4.39
PHP 7.3.4
MariaDB 10.2.11

Thanks for any help and ideas.

Comment: what LogLevel is set on your Apache? Please set it ro debug an have a look if there is an error in your log file next time.

Comment: It whas on "warn", tried "debug" but much lines for not more informations. I've juste put it back on "debug" in case and waiting for next bug...